# Error in scale_fill_gradientn() function in R: Discrete values supplied to continuous scale

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am encountering an error while creating a heatmap plot in R using ggplot2. When attempting to use the scale_fill_gradientn() function to specify colors for the heatmap, I encounter the following error:

```
Error in `scale_fill_gradientn()`:
! Discrete values supplied to continuous scale.
ℹ Example values: "0", "0", "0", "0", and "0"
Run `rlang::last_trace()` to see where the error occurred.
```

Here is the relevant portion of the code:

```
# Install and load required packages
library(ggplot2)

colors <- c("#f7f9cb", "#c7edc0", "#92e0c3", "#56d0d0", "#00bdde", "#00afef", "#539df4", "#9085e8", "#cd6ace", "#f54a9d", "#ff3d5e", "#f0550d", "#fc8d59")

# Create the plot
ggplot(data, aes(x = tm, y = characteristic, fill = number)) +
  geom_tile(color = "black", size = 0.2) +
  geom_text(aes(label = ifelse(number != 0, number, "")), size = 3) +
  scale_fill_gradientn(colors = colors) +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, vjust = 0.5, hjust = 1),
        panel.border = element_rect(color = "black", fill = NA, size = 1),
        axis.line = element_line(color = "black"),
        plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5, face = "bold", size = 14),
        axis.title = element_text(face = "bold", size = 12),
        axis.text = element_text(size = 10, face = "bold"),
        legend.title = element_text(face = "bold", size = 12),
        legend.text = element_text(size = 10, face = "bold"),
        legend.box.background = element_rect(color = "black", size = 1)) +
  labs(title = "Heatmap of Amino Acid Properties vs Inter-TM",
       x = "Transmembrane Regions",
       y = "Properties",
       fill = "Number of \nResidual Pairs") +
  coord_fixed()
```

The input data consists of three columns: number, characteristic, and tm:

```
number  characteristic  tm
0   Acidic-Aliphatic    TM1-TM2
0   Acidic-Aromatic TM1-TM2
0   Acidic-Hydroxyl TM1-TM2
0   Acidic-Small    TM1-TM2
0   Aliphatic-Amide TM1-TM2
0   Aliphatic-Aromatic  TM1-TM2
0   Aliphatic-Basic TM1-TM2
0   Aliphatic-Hydroxyl  TM1-TM2
0   Aliphatic-Small TM1-TM2
0   Aliphatic-Sulfur    TM1-TM2
0   Amide-Acidic    TM1-TM2
0   Amide-Aliphatic TM1-TM2
0   Amide-Aromatic  TM1-TM2
0   Amide-Aromatic  TM1-TM2
0   Amide-Hydroxyl  TM1-TM2
0   Aromatic-Aromatic   TM1-TM2
0   Aromatic-Hydroxyl   TM1-TM2
0   Aromatic-Aliphatic  TM1-TM2
0   Basic-Aliphatic TM1-TM2
0   Basic-Aromatic  TM1-TM2
0   Basic-Aromatic  TM1-TM2
0   Basic-Aromatic  TM1-TM2
0   Basic-Basic TM1-TM2
0   Basic-Hydroxyl  TM1-TM2
0   Basic-Small TM1-TM2
0   Basic-Sulfur    TM1-TM2
0   Hydroxyl-Aliphatic  TM1-TM2
0   Hydroxyl-Aromatic   TM1-TM2
0   Hydroxyl-Hydroxyl   TM1-TM2
0   Small-Aliphatic TM1-TM2
0   Small-Hydroxyl  TM1-TM2
0   Sulfur-Aliphatic    TM1-TM2
0   Sulfur-Amide    TM1-TM2
0   Sulfur-Aromatic TM1-TM2
0   Sulfur-Hydroxyl TM1-TM2
0   Sulfur-Small    TM1-TM2
1   Amide-Basic TM1-TM2
1   Aromatic-Aromatic   TM1-TM2
1   Aromatic-Aromatic   TM1-TM2
1   Basic-Aliphatic TM1-TM2
1   Basic-Amide TM1-TM2
1   Basic-Aromatic  TM1-TM2
1   Small-Aromatic  TM1-TM2
2   Acidic-Aromatic TM1-TM2
2   Acidic-Basic    TM1-TM2
2   Aliphatic-Aromatic  TM1-TM2
4   Aromatic-Aliphatic  TM1-TM2
8   Basic-Acidic    TM1-TM2
9   Aliphatic-Aliphatic TM1-TM2
0   Acidic-Aliphatic    TM1-TM3
0   Acidic-Aromatic TM1-TM3
0   Acidic-Aromatic TM1-TM3
0   Acidic-Hydroxyl TM1-TM3
0   Acidic-Small    TM1-TM3
0   Aliphatic-Aliphatic TM1-TM3
0   Aliphatic-Amide TM1-TM3
0   Aliphatic-Aromatic  TM1-TM3
0   Aliphatic-Aromatic  TM1-TM3
0   Aliphatic-Basic TM1-TM3
0   Aliphatic-Hydroxyl  TM1-TM3
0   Aliphatic-Small TM1-TM3
0   Aliphatic-Sulfur    TM1-TM3
0   Amide-Acidic    TM1-TM3
0   Amide-Aliphatic TM1-TM3
0   Amide-Aromatic  TM1-TM3
0   Amide-Aromatic  TM1-TM3
0   Amide-Basic TM1-TM3
0   Amide-Hydroxyl  TM1-TM3
0   Aromatic-Aliphatic  TM1-TM3
0   Aromatic-Aromatic   TM1-TM3
0   Aromatic-Aromatic   TM1-TM3
0   Aromatic-Hydroxyl   TM1-TM3
0   Aromatic-Aliphatic  TM1-TM3
0   Aromatic-Aromatic   TM1-TM3
0   Basic-Aliphatic TM1-TM3
0   Basic-Aromatic  TM1-TM3
0   Basic-Aromatic  TM1-TM3
0   Basic-Acidic    TM1-TM3
0   Basic-Aliphatic TM1-TM3
0   Basic-Amide TM1-TM3
0   Basic-Aromatic  TM1-TM3
0   Basic-Aromatic  TM1-TM3
0   Basic-Basic TM1-TM3
0   Basic-Hydroxyl  TM1-TM3
0   Basic-Small TM1-TM3
0   Basic-Sulfur    TM1-TM3
0   Hydroxyl-Aliphatic  TM1-TM3
0   Hydroxyl-Aromatic   TM1-TM3
0   Hydroxyl-Hydroxyl   TM1-TM3
0   Small-Aliphatic TM1-TM3
0   Small-Aromatic  TM1-TM3
0   Small-Hydroxyl  TM1-TM3
0   Sulfur-Aliphatic    TM1-TM3
0   Sulfur-Amide    TM1-TM3
0   Sulfur-Aromatic TM1-TM3
0   Sulfur-Hydroxyl TM1-TM3
0   Sulfur-Small    TM1-TM3
3   Acidic-Basic    TM1-TM3
0   Acidic-Aromatic TM1-TM7
0   Acidic-Basic    TM1-TM7
0   Acidic-Hydroxyl TM1-TM7
0   Acidic-Small    TM1-TM7
0   Aliphatic-Aromatic  TM1-TM7
0   Aliphatic-Small TM1-TM7
0   Amide-Aromatic  TM1-TM7
0   Amide-Aromatic  TM1-TM7
0   Amide-Basic TM1-TM7
0   Aromatic-Aromatic   TM1-TM7
0   Aromatic-Aromatic   TM1-TM7
0   Aromatic-Aromatic   TM1-TM7
0   Basic-Aliphatic TM1-TM7
0   Basic-Aromatic  TM1-TM7
0   Basic-Aromatic  TM1-TM7
0   Basic-Acidic    TM1-TM7
0   Basic-Aromatic  TM1-TM7
0   Basic-Basic TM1-TM7
0   Basic-Small TM1-TM7
0   Basic-Sulfur    TM1-TM7
0   Hydroxyl-Aliphatic  TM1-TM7
0   Hydroxyl-Aromatic   TM1-TM7
0   Hydroxyl-Hydroxyl   TM1-TM7
0   Small-Aliphatic TM1-TM7
0   Small-Aromatic  TM1-TM7
0   Small-Hydroxyl  TM1-TM7
0   Sulfur-Aliphatic    TM1-TM7
0   Sulfur-Amide    TM1-TM7
0   Sulfur-Aromatic TM1-TM7
0   Sulfur-Hydroxyl TM1-TM7
0   Sulfur-Small    TM1-TM7
1   Aliphatic-Amide TM1-TM7
1   Aliphatic-Basic TM1-TM7
1   Amide-Acidic    TM1-TM7
25  Aliphatic-Aliphatic TM1-TM7
2   Aliphatic-Sulfur    TM1-TM7
2   Amide-Aliphatic TM1-TM7
2   Aromatic-Hydroxyl   TM1-TM7
2   Aromatic-Aliphatic  TM1-TM7
2   Basic-Hydroxyl  TM1-TM7
3   Acidic-Aliphatic    TM1-TM7
3   Aliphatic-Aromatic  TM1-TM7
3   Amide-Hydroxyl  TM1-TM7
3   Basic-Aliphatic TM1-TM7
3   Basic-Amide TM1-TM7
3   Basic-Aromatic  TM1-TM7
4   Acidic-Aromatic TM1-TM7
5   Aromatic-Aliphatic  TM1-TM7
6   Aliphatic-Hydroxyl  TM1-TM7
0   Acidic-Aliphatic    TM2-TM3
0   Acidic-Aromatic TM2-TM3
0   Acidic-Aromatic TM2-TM3
0   Aliphatic-Amide TM2-TM3
0   Aliphatic-Sulfur    TM2-TM3
0   Amide-Acidic    TM2-TM3
0   Amide-Aliphatic TM2-TM3
0   Amide-Aromatic  TM2-TM3
0   Amide-Basic TM2-TM3
0   Amide-Hydroxyl  TM2-TM3
0   Aromatic-Aliphatic  TM2-TM3
0   Aromatic-Aromatic   TM2-TM3
0   Aromatic-Aliphatic  TM2-TM3
0   Aromatic-Aromatic   TM2-TM3
0   Basic-Aliphatic TM2-TM3
0   Basic-Aromatic  TM2-TM3
0   Basic-Aromatic  TM2-TM3
0   Basic-Aliphatic TM2-TM3
0   Basic-Amide TM2-TM3
0   Basic-Aromatic  TM2-TM3
0   Basic-Basic TM2-TM3
0   Basic-Sulfur    TM2-TM3
0   Hydroxyl-Hydroxyl   TM2-TM3
0   Small-Aliphatic TM2-TM3
0   Small-Aromatic  TM2-TM3
0   Small-Hydroxyl  TM2-TM3
0   Sulfur-Aromatic TM2-TM3
11  Aliphatic-Aromatic  TM2-TM3
1   Acidic-Basic    TM2-TM3
1   Aliphatic-Basic TM2-TM3
1   Aromatic-Aromatic   TM2-TM3
1   Aromatic-Hydroxyl   TM2-TM3
1   Basic-Aromatic  TM2-TM3
1   Basic-Hydroxyl  TM2-TM3
1   Basic-Small TM2-TM3
1   Sulfur-Amide    TM2-TM3
1   Sulfur-Small    TM2-TM3
20  Aliphatic-Aliphatic TM2-TM3
2   Acidic-Hydroxyl TM2-TM3
2   Aliphatic-Aromatic  TM2-TM3
2   Aliphatic-Small TM2-TM3
2   Amide-Aromatic  TM2-TM3
2   Basic-Acidic    TM2-TM3
2   Hydroxyl-Aromatic   TM2-TM3
2   Sulfur-Aliphatic    TM2-TM3
2   Sulfur-Hydroxyl TM2-TM3
3   Acidic-Small    TM2-TM3
3   Hydroxyl-Aliphatic  TM2-TM3
6   Aliphatic-Hydroxyl  TM2-TM3
0   Acidic-Aliphatic    TM2-TM7
0   Acidic-Aromatic TM2-TM7
0   Acidic-Aromatic TM2-TM7
0   Acidic-Basic    TM2-TM7
0   Acidic-Hydroxyl TM2-TM7
0   Acidic-Small    TM2-TM7
0   Aliphatic-Aliphatic TM2-TM7
0   Aliphatic-Amide TM2-TM7
0   Aliphatic-Aromatic  TM2-TM7
0   Aliphatic-Basic TM2-TM7
0   Aliphatic-Hydroxyl  TM2-TM7
0   Aliphatic-Small TM2-TM7
0   Aliphatic-Sulfur    TM2-TM7
0   Amide-Acidic    TM2-TM7
0   Amide-Aliphatic TM2-TM7
0   Amide-Aromatic  TM2-TM7
0   Amide-Aromatic  TM2-TM7
0   Amide-Basic TM2-TM7
0   Amide-Hydroxyl  TM2-TM7
0   Aromatic-Aromatic   TM2-TM7
0   Aromatic-Aromatic   TM2-TM7
0   Aromatic-Hydroxyl   TM2-TM7
0   Aromatic-Aliphatic  TM2-TM7
0   Aromatic-Aromatic   TM2-TM7
0   Basic-Aliphatic TM2-TM7
0   Basic-Aromatic  TM2-TM7
0   Basic-Aromatic  TM2-TM7
0   Basic-Acidic    TM2-TM7
0   Basic-Aliphatic TM2-TM7
0   Basic-Amide TM2-TM7
0   Basic-Aromatic  TM2-TM7
0   Basic-Basic TM2-TM7
0   Basic-Hydroxyl  TM2-TM7
0   Basic-Small TM2-TM7
0   Basic-Sulfur    TM2-TM7
0   Hydroxyl-Aliphatic  TM2-TM7
0   Hydroxyl-Aromatic   TM2-TM7
0   Hydroxyl-Hydroxyl   TM2-TM7
0   Small-Aliphatic TM2-TM7
0   Small-Aromatic  TM2-TM7
0   Small-Hydroxyl  TM2-TM7
0   Sulfur-Aliphatic    TM2-TM7
0   Sulfur-Amide    TM2-TM7
0   Sulfur-Aromatic TM2-TM7
0   Sulfur-Hydroxyl TM2-TM7
0   Sulfur-Small    TM2-TM7
1   Aliphatic-Aromatic  TM2-TM7
1   Aromatic-Aliphatic  TM2-TM7
1   Basic-Aromatic  TM2-TM7
0   Acidic-Aliphatic    TM3-TM4
0   Acidic-Aromatic TM3-TM4
0   Acidic-Aromatic TM3-TM4
0   Acidic-Hydroxyl TM3-TM4
0   Acidic-Small    TM3-TM4
0   Aliphatic-Amide TM3-TM4
0   Aliphatic-Basic TM3-TM4
0   Aliphatic-Sulfur    TM3-TM4
0   Amide-Acidic    TM3-TM4
0   Amide-Basic TM3-TM4
0   Amide-Hydroxyl  TM3-TM4
0   Basic-Aliphatic TM3-TM4
0   Basic-Aromatic  TM3-TM4
0   Basic-Aromatic  TM3-TM4
0   Basic-Acidic    TM3-TM4
0   Basic-Amide TM3-TM4
0   Basic-Aromatic  TM3-TM4
0   Basic-Basic TM3-TM4
0   Basic-Hydroxyl  TM3-TM4
0   Basic-Small TM3-TM4
0   Basic-Sulfur    TM3-TM4
0   Hydroxyl-Aliphatic  TM3-TM4
0   Hydroxyl-Aromatic   TM3-TM4
0   Hydroxyl-Hydroxyl   TM3-TM4
0   Small-Hydroxyl  TM3-TM4
0   Sulfur-Aliphatic    TM3-TM4
0   Sulfur-Amide    TM3-TM4
0   Sulfur-Aromatic TM3-TM4
0   Sulfur-Hydroxyl TM3-TM4
0   Sulfur-Small    TM3-TM4
1   Acidic-Basic    TM3-TM4
1   Aliphatic-Small TM3-TM4
1   Amide-Aliphatic TM3-TM4
1   Amide-Aromatic  TM3-TM4
1   Amide-Aromatic  TM3-TM4
1   Aromatic-Aromatic   TM3-TM4
1   Aromatic-Aromatic   TM3-TM4
1   Aromatic-Aliphatic  TM3-TM4
1   Aromatic-Aromatic   TM3-TM4
1   Small-Aliphatic TM3-TM4
1   Small-Aromatic  TM3-TM4
2   Basic-Aromatic  TM3-TM4
3   Aromatic-Hydroxyl   TM3-TM4
4   Aliphatic-Hydroxyl  TM3-TM4
4   Basic-Aliphatic TM3-TM4
5   Aliphatic-Aromatic  TM3-TM4
7   Aliphatic-Aromatic  TM3-TM4
8   Aliphatic-Aliphatic TM3-TM4
8   Aromatic-Aliphatic  TM3-TM4
0   Acidic-Aliphatic    TM3-TM5
0   Acidic-Aromatic TM3-TM5
0   Acidic-Aromatic TM3-TM5
0   Acidic-Basic    TM3-TM5
0   Acidic-Hydroxyl TM3-TM5
0   Acidic-Small    TM3-TM5
0   Aliphatic-Aliphatic TM3-TM5
0   Aliphatic-Amide TM3-TM5
0   Aliphatic-Aromatic  TM3-TM5
0   Aliphatic-Aromatic  TM3-TM5
0   Aliphatic-Basic TM3-TM5
0   Aliphatic-Hydroxyl  TM3-TM5
0   Aliphatic-Small TM3-TM5
0   Aliphatic-Sulfur    TM3-TM5
0   Amide-Acidic    TM3-TM5
0   Amide-Aliphatic TM3-TM5
0   Amide-Aromatic  TM3-TM5
0   Amide-Aromatic  TM3-TM5
0   Amide-Basic TM3-TM5
0   Amide-Hydroxyl  TM3-TM5
0   Aromatic-Aromatic   TM3-TM5
0   Aromatic-Aromatic   TM3-TM5
0   Aromatic-Hydroxyl   TM3-TM5
0   Aromatic-Aliphatic  TM3-TM5
0   Aromatic-Aromatic   TM3-TM5
0   Basic-Aliphatic TM3-TM5
0   Basic-Aromatic  TM3-TM5
0   Basic-Aromatic  TM3-TM5
0   Basic-Acidic    TM3-TM5
0   Basic-Aliphatic TM3-TM5
0   Basic-Amide TM3-TM5
0   Basic-Aromatic  TM3-TM5
0   Basic-Aromatic  TM3-TM5
0   Basic-Basic TM3-TM5
0   Basic-Hydroxyl  TM3-TM5
0   Basic-Small TM3-TM5
0   Basic-Sulfur    TM3-TM5
0   Hydroxyl-Aliphatic  TM3-TM5
0   Hydroxyl-Hydroxyl   TM3-TM5
0   Small-Aliphatic TM3-TM5
0   Small-Aromatic  TM3-TM5
0   Small-Hydroxyl  TM3-TM5
0   Sulfur-Aliphatic    TM3-TM5
0   Sulfur-Amide    TM3-TM5
0   Sulfur-Aromatic TM3-TM5
0   Sulfur-Hydroxyl TM3-TM5
0   Sulfur-Small    TM3-TM5
1   Hydroxyl-Aromatic   TM3-TM5
2   Aromatic-Aliphatic  TM3-TM5
0   Acidic-Aliphatic    TM3-TM7
0   Acidic-Aromatic TM3-TM7
0   Acidic-Aromatic TM3-TM7
0   Acidic-Basic    TM3-TM7
0   Acidic-Hydroxyl TM3-TM7
0   Acidic-Small    TM3-TM7
0   Aliphatic-Aliphatic TM3-TM7
0   Aliphatic-Amide TM3-TM7
0   Aliphatic-Aromatic  TM3-TM7
0   Aliphatic-Aromatic  TM3-TM7
0   Aliphatic-Basic TM3-TM7
0   Aliphatic-Hydroxyl  TM3-TM7
0   Aliphatic-Small TM3-TM7
0   Aliphatic-Sulfur    TM3-TM7
0   Amide-Acidic    TM3-TM7
0   Amide-Aliphatic TM3-TM7
0   Amide-Aromatic  TM3-TM7
0   Amide-Aromatic  TM3-TM7
0   Amide-Basic TM3-TM7
0   Amide-Hydroxyl  TM3-TM7
0   Aromatic-Aliphatic  TM3-TM7
0   Aromatic-Aromatic   TM3-TM7
0   Aromatic-Aromatic   TM3-TM7
0   Aromatic-Hydroxyl   TM3-TM7
0   Aromatic-Aliphatic  TM3-TM7
0   Aromatic-Aromatic   TM3-TM7
0   Basic-Aliphatic TM3-TM7
0   Basic-Aromatic  TM3-TM7
0   Basic-Aromatic  TM3-TM7
0   Basic-Acidic    TM3-TM7
0   Basic-Aliphatic TM3-TM7
0   Basic-Amide TM3-TM7
0   Basic-Aromatic  TM3-TM7
0   Basic-Basic TM3-TM7
0   Basic-Hydroxyl  TM3-TM7
0   Basic-Small TM3-TM7
0   Basic-Sulfur    TM3-TM7
0   Hydroxyl-Aliphatic  TM3-TM7
0   Hydroxyl-Aromatic   TM3-TM7
0   Hydroxyl-Hydroxyl   TM3-TM7
0   Small-Aliphatic TM3-TM7
0   Small-Aromatic  TM3-TM7
0   Small-Hydroxyl  TM3-TM7
0   Sulfur-Aliphatic    TM3-TM7
0   Sulfur-Amide    TM3-TM7
0   Sulfur-Aromatic TM3-TM7
0   Sulfur-Hydroxyl TM3-TM7
0   Sulfur-Small    TM3-TM7
1   Basic-Aromatic  TM3-TM7
0   Acidic-Aromatic TM4-TM5
0   Acidic-Aromatic TM4-TM5
0   Acidic-Basic    TM4-TM5
0   Acidic-Small    TM4-TM5
0   Aliphatic-Amide TM4-TM5
0   Aliphatic-Sulfur    TM4-TM5
0   Amide-Acidic    TM4-TM5
0   Amide-Aromatic  TM4-TM5
0   Amide-Aromatic  TM4-TM5
0   Amide-Basic TM4-TM5
0   Aromatic-Aliphatic  TM4-TM5
0   Aromatic-Aromatic   TM4-TM5
0   Basic-Aliphatic TM4-TM5
0   Basic-Aromatic  TM4-TM5
0   Basic-Aromatic  TM4-TM5
0   Basic-Amide TM4-TM5
0   Basic-Aromatic  TM4-TM5
0   Basic-Hydroxyl  TM4-TM5
0   Basic-Small TM4-TM5
0   Basic-Sulfur    TM4-TM5
0   Sulfur-Aliphatic    TM4-TM5
0   Sulfur-Amide    TM4-TM5
0   Sulfur-Aromatic TM4-TM5
0   Sulfur-Hydroxyl TM4-TM5
0   Sulfur-Small    TM4-TM5
17  Aliphatic-Aromatic  TM4-TM5
19  Aliphatic-Aliphatic TM4-TM5
1   Acidic-Hydroxyl TM4-TM5
1   Aliphatic-Basic TM4-TM5
1   Aliphatic-Small TM4-TM5
1   Amide-Aliphatic TM4-TM5
1   Amide-Hydroxyl  TM4-TM5
1   Aromatic-Aromatic   TM4-TM5
1   Aromatic-Aromatic   TM4-TM5
1   Basic-Aromatic  TM4-TM5
1   Basic-Basic TM4-TM5
1   Hydroxyl-Aliphatic  TM4-TM5
1   Small-Hydroxyl  TM4-TM5
2   Aliphatic-Hydroxyl  TM4-TM5
2   Aromatic-Hydroxyl   TM4-TM5
2   Aromatic-Aliphatic  TM4-TM5
2   Hydroxyl-Hydroxyl   TM4-TM5
3   Basic-Aliphatic TM4-TM5
4   Acidic-Aliphatic    TM4-TM5
4   Aliphatic-Aromatic  TM4-TM5
5   Basic-Acidic    TM4-TM5
5   Hydroxyl-Aromatic   TM4-TM5
5   Small-Aliphatic TM4-TM5
7   Small-Aromatic  TM4-TM5
0   Acidic-Aromatic TM5-TM6
0   Acidic-Aromatic TM5-TM6
0   Acidic-Hydroxyl TM5-TM6
0   Acidic-Small    TM5-TM6
0   Aliphatic-Amide TM5-TM6
0   Aliphatic-Basic TM5-TM6
0   Aliphatic-Hydroxyl  TM5-TM6
0   Aliphatic-Small TM5-TM6
0   Aliphatic-Sulfur    TM5-TM6
0   Amide-Acidic    TM5-TM6
0   Amide-Aliphatic TM5-TM6
0   Amide-Aromatic  TM5-TM6
0   Amide-Basic TM5-TM6
0   Amide-Hydroxyl  TM5-TM6
0   Aromatic-Aliphatic  TM5-TM6
0   Aromatic-Aliphatic  TM5-TM6
0   Aromatic-Aromatic   TM5-TM6
0   Basic-Aliphatic TM5-TM6
0   Basic-Aromatic  TM5-TM6
0   Basic-Aromatic  TM5-TM6
0   Basic-Aliphatic TM5-TM6
0   Basic-Amide TM5-TM6
0   Basic-Aromatic  TM5-TM6
0   Basic-Aromatic  TM5-TM6
0   Basic-Basic TM5-TM6
0   Basic-Hydroxyl  TM5-TM6
0   Basic-Small TM5-TM6
0   Basic-Sulfur    TM5-TM6
0   Hydroxyl-Aliphatic  TM5-TM6
0   Hydroxyl-Hydroxyl   TM5-TM6
0   Small-Aliphatic TM5-TM6
0   Small-Aromatic  TM5-TM6
0   Small-Hydroxyl  TM5-TM6
0   Sulfur-Aliphatic    TM5-TM6
0   Sulfur-Amide    TM5-TM6
0   Sulfur-Aromatic TM5-TM6
0   Sulfur-Hydroxyl TM5-TM6
0   Sulfur-Small    TM5-TM6
1   Acidic-Aliphatic    TM5-TM6
1   Acidic-Basic    TM5-TM6
1   Aliphatic-Aromatic  TM5-TM6
1   Aliphatic-Aromatic  TM5-TM6
1   Aromatic-Aromatic   TM5-TM6
1   Hydroxyl-Aromatic   TM5-TM6
2   Amide-Aromatic  TM5-TM6
2   Aromatic-Hydroxyl   TM5-TM6
2   Basic-Acidic    TM5-TM6
3   Aromatic-Aromatic   TM5-TM6
6   Aliphatic-Aliphatic TM5-TM6
0   Acidic-Aliphatic    TM5-TM7
0   Acidic-Aromatic TM5-TM7
0   Acidic-Aromatic TM5-TM7
0   Acidic-Basic    TM5-TM7
0   Acidic-Hydroxyl TM5-TM7
0   Acidic-Small    TM5-TM7
0   Aliphatic-Aliphatic TM5-TM7
0   Aliphatic-Amide TM5-TM7
0   Aliphatic-Aromatic  TM5-TM7
0   Aliphatic-Aromatic  TM5-TM7
0   Aliphatic-Basic TM5-TM7
0   Aliphatic-Hydroxyl  TM5-TM7
0   Aliphatic-Small TM5-TM7
0   Aliphatic-Sulfur    TM5-TM7
0   Amide-Acidic    TM5-TM7
0   Amide-Aliphatic TM5-TM7
0   Amide-Aromatic  TM5-TM7
0   Amide-Aromatic  TM5-TM7
0   Amide-Basic TM5-TM7
0   Amide-Hydroxyl  TM5-TM7
0   Aromatic-Aliphatic  TM5-TM7
0   Aromatic-Aromatic   TM5-TM7
0   Aromatic-Aromatic   TM5-TM7
0   Aromatic-Hydroxyl   TM5-TM7
0   Aromatic-Aliphatic  TM5-TM7
0   Aromatic-Aromatic   TM5-TM7
0   Basic-Aliphatic TM5-TM7
0   Basic-Aromatic  TM5-TM7
0   Basic-Aromatic  TM5-TM7
0   Basic-Acidic    TM5-TM7
0   Basic-Aliphatic TM5-TM7
0   Basic-Amide TM5-TM7
0   Basic-Aromatic  TM5-TM7
0   Basic-Basic TM5-TM7
0   Basic-Hydroxyl  TM5-TM7
0   Basic-Small TM5-TM7
0   Basic-Sulfur    TM5-TM7
0   Hydroxyl-Aliphatic  TM5-TM7
0   Hydroxyl-Aromatic   TM5-TM7
0   Hydroxyl-Hydroxyl   TM5-TM7
0   Small-Aliphatic TM5-TM7
0   Small-Aromatic  TM5-TM7
0   Small-Hydroxyl  TM5-TM7
0   Sulfur-Aliphatic    TM5-TM7
0   Sulfur-Amide    TM5-TM7
0   Sulfur-Aromatic TM5-TM7
0   Sulfur-Hydroxyl TM5-TM7
0   Sulfur-Small    TM5-TM7
1   Basic-Aromatic  TM5-TM7
0   Acidic-Basic    TM6-TM7
0   Acidic-Hydroxyl TM6-TM7
0   Acidic-Small    TM6-TM7
0   Aliphatic-Amide TM6-TM7
0   Aliphatic-Basic TM6-TM7
0   Aliphatic-Small TM6-TM7
0   Amide-Acidic    TM6-TM7
0   Amide-Basic TM6-TM7
0   Aromatic-Aromatic   TM6-TM7
0   Aromatic-Aromatic   TM6-TM7
0   Aromatic-Aliphatic  TM6-TM7
0   Aromatic-Aromatic   TM6-TM7
0   Basic-Acidic    TM6-TM7
0   Basic-Aromatic  TM6-TM7
0   Basic-Basic TM6-TM7
0   Basic-Hydroxyl  TM6-TM7
0   Basic-Small TM6-TM7
0   Small-Aromatic  TM6-TM7
0   Sulfur-Amide    TM6-TM7
0   Sulfur-Hydroxyl TM6-TM7
0   Sulfur-Small    TM6-TM7
1   Acidic-Aliphatic    TM6-TM7
1   Acidic-Aromatic TM6-TM7
1   Amide-Aromatic  TM6-TM7
1   Amide-Aromatic  TM6-TM7
1   Amide-Hydroxyl  TM6-TM7
1   Aromatic-Hydroxyl   TM6-TM7
1   Basic-Aromatic  TM6-TM7
1   Basic-Aromatic  TM6-TM7
1   Basic-Amide TM6-TM7
1   Hydroxyl-Aliphatic  TM6-TM7
1   Hydroxyl-Aromatic   TM6-TM7
1   Sulfur-Aliphatic    TM6-TM7
2   Acidic-Aromatic TM6-TM7
2   Aliphatic-Aromatic  TM6-TM7
2   Amide-Aliphatic TM6-TM7
2   Basic-Aliphatic TM6-TM7
2   Basic-Aliphatic TM6-TM7
2   Basic-Sulfur    TM6-TM7
2   Small-Aliphatic TM6-TM7
2   Sulfur-Aromatic TM6-TM7
37  Aliphatic-Aliphatic TM6-TM7
3   Aliphatic-Sulfur    TM6-TM7
3   Hydroxyl-Hydroxyl   TM6-TM7
4   Aromatic-Aliphatic  TM6-TM7
4   Basic-Aromatic  TM6-TM7
4   Small-Hydroxyl  TM6-TM7
5   Aliphatic-Hydroxyl  TM6-TM7
8   Aliphatic-Aromatic  TM6-TM7
```

I'm not sure how to address this issue.

Could someone please help me understand why this error occurs and how to resolve it? Any insights or alternative approaches to creating the heatmap would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Can you show the output of `str(data)`?

Comment: It looks like your `number` variable is a character, not numeric.

Comment: Try with explicitly converting to a numeric, e.g. `fill = as.numeric(number)`.